# Pyinstaller executable closes instantly

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pyinstaller, portable-executable

I need to create a one file portable executable. I wrote a python program for word suggestions and I wanted to build a one file executable for the program. I ran `pyinstaller --F prog.py` 
However, the exe file built from this does not run and instead just shows a blank screen. My program:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import timeit
import copy

dictionary = {}
with open('EnglishDictionary.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for rows in reader:
        dictionary[rows[0]] = int(rows[1])
dictionary = dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

a = sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)
def recommend(word):
    global a
    count = 0
    num = len(word)
    res = []
    a = [i for i in a if i[:num]==word]
    if len(a)>5:
        return a[:5]
    elif len(a)==0:
        return ['No match found!']
    else:
        return a

word = ''
char = ''
while(1):
    char = input("Enter character: ")[0]
    if char=='#':
        break
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    word+=char
    x = recommend(word)
    time = str(int((timeit.default_timer() - start_time)*(10**6)))+' microseconds'
    for i in x:
        if i!=x[-1]:
            i+=','
        print("{0: <10}".format(i),end=' ')
    print(time)
    if x[0]=='No match found!':
        print("Exiting")
        break
```

I'm new to building executables from python files. So if any other way to build that works would also be very helpful!
Link to CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UJl_TjV_JlMVS9XCGLEXfboPXO4lMi3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 1. Try running it from the command-line
2. Isn't the blank screen for the line which expects the `input("Enter char...")`

Comment: It does, however it doesn't take any input either. I ran it from terminal and it works properly from there